# MySQL privilege needed to grant "SHOW INDEX" access

Tags: mysql

I'd like a monitor user be able to (only) execute "SHOW INDEX" and "SHOW TABLES" on a certain database. What privileges should I `GRANT` this user?

I'd rather not open up for the user to be able to do `SELECT`s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `SELECT` is necessary for both of these commands.  I suspect the only way to be absolutely certain is to test this performance.

Arthur Ogawa's [comment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show.html) reinforces my suspicion.